# Does normal force at various instant have any effect on the acceleration or retardation of ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

If there is a Body rolling on a frictionless smooth surface.It a double inclined plane.

We say $h$ of the Body initial is = final (Nearly) h = h’

We also see that normal force is changing at every instant but mg is always downwards.Does the N force given any affect in acceleration or retardation of ball.

[image]

Comment: What do you think is giving the ball acceleration horizontally?

Comment: @JustJohan Horizontally.Acceleration component along x axis = 0 and along y axis = -g.

Comment: Ball is just left.No force was applied on it at initial position.

Comment: okay, then why does it move to the right?

Comment: Because of inclined plane ? I am not getting the right answer.@JustJohan

Comment: The normal force has a component vertically and horizontally at some points during its motion. Do you not think the horizontal component will accelerate/retard it horizontally?

Comment: Yes it will.Ok And can we say that the force acting on body is also variable due to changing angles of horizontal normal @JustJohan

Comment: That is a whole new question, but yes we can say that.

Comment: @JustJohan That is amazing.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal reaction affects the radial acceleration (not the tangential acceleration ,  as it is perpendicular to it).